# How to convert string tuple into float colums in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I convert this dataframe

| Coordinate (X, Y) | value |
| --- | --- |
| (46.8637, 2.3134) | 001 |
| (42.8637, 2.5134) | 002 |

to this:

| X | Y | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46.8637 | 2.3134 | 001 |
| 42.8637 | 2.5134 | 002 |

When I tried this method :

```
col_list = ['X', 'Y']
for n,col in enumerate(col_list):
    temp_dict[col] = temp_dict['Coordinate  (X, Y)'].apply(lambda location: location[n])
```

The result is:

| X | Y | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 001 |
| 4 | 2 | 002 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Coordinate  (X, Y)': ['(46.8637, 2.3134)', '(42.8637, 2.5134)'],
...     'value': ['001', '002']
... })
>>> df
  Coordinate  (X, Y) value
0  (46.8637, 2.3134)   001
1  (42.8637, 2.5134)   002
>>> df[['X', 'Y']] = df['Coordinate  (X, Y)'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)
>>> df.drop('Coordinate  (X, Y)', axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df = df[['X', 'Y', 'value']]
>>> df
         X       Y value
0  46.8637  2.3134   001
1  42.8637  2.5134   002
```